# Search for overlapping date ranges

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have product collection with a list of date ranges that represent dates when products are rented. So it looks something like this:

```
"product" : {
...
 "RentalPeriods" : [
  {
   "From" : ISODate("2017-02-11T23:00:00.000Z"),
   "To" : ISODate("2017-02-12T23:00:00.000Z")
  },
  {
   "From" : ISODate("2017-10-09T23:00:00.000Z"),
   "To" : ISODate("2017-10-21T23:00:00.000Z")
  }
]
...
}
```

I want to create query that will go through all products and to return only products that can be rented for provided date range.
So if I provide something like:

RentalPeriod("2017-03-03", "2017-03-04") - it should return above product

RentalPeriod("2017-02-03", "2017-02-14") - it should not return above product

We tried with LINQ expression, but we got Unsupported filter Exception.

So this is what we tried:

```
public Expression<Func<Product, bool>> IsSatisfied() =>
            product => product.RentalPeriods.All(rentPeriod => !(_fromDate > rentPeriod.FromDate && _fromDate < rentPeriod.MaybeToDate.Value) &&
                                                                !(rentPeriod.FromDate > _fromDate  && rentPeriod.FromDate < _toDate));
```

(Above query is partial, but I suppose it is clear what we tried).

Is there any other way how we can achieve this?

**Edit 13-12-2017**:

```
public class AvailabilityForRentalPeriodSpecification : ISpecification<Product>
    {
        private UtcDate _fromDate;
        private UtcDate _toDate;

        public AvailabilityForRentalPeriodSpecification(RentalPeriod rentalPeriod)
        {
            _fromDate = rentalPeriod.FromDate;
            _toDate = rentalPeriod.MaybeToDate.Value;
        }

        public Expression<Func<Product, bool>> IsSatisfied() =>
            product => product.RentalPeriods.All(rentPeriod => !(_fromDate > rentPeriod.FromDate && _fromDate < rentPeriod.MaybeToDate.Value) &&
                                                                !(rentPeriod.FromDate > _fromDate  && rentPeriod.FromDate < _toDate));
    }
```

This specification is used in DAO layer as:

```
public IList<T> GetBy(ISpecification<T> specification)
            => _mongoCollection.Find(specification.IsSatisfied()).ToList();
```

Possible solution (that I'm trying to avoid) is to retrieve all products from DB and then to filter them in the code.

Comment: Please show how you use the `IsSatisfied` expression in your LINQ query and where the expression, `_fromDate`, and `_toDate` are declared.

Comment: @GertArnold I updated question

Comment: Can you even use "<", ">" with DateTime in the mongoDb LINQ provider? Try to execute the query with the expression a plain lambda expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a query logic to use *Any* method instead of unsupported *All* method, so it looks like this now:

```
public Expression<Func<Product, bool>> IsSatisfied() =>
            product => !product.RentalPeriods.Any(dbRentalPeriod => _fromDate >= dbRentalPeriod.FromDate && _fromDate <= dbRentalPeriod.ToDate ||
                                                                    _toDate >= dbRentalPeriod.FromDate && _toDate <= dbRentalPeriod.ToDate ||
                                                                    dbRentalPeriod.FromDate >= _fromDate && dbRentalPeriod.ToDate <= _toDate);
```

Another problem was using Maybe struct for *ToDate* (rentPeriod.MaybeToDate.Value), which is resolved by creating internal DateTime field next to the MaybeToDate field.